# I keep getting this error when trying to call my applications

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

This error keeps coming up on all applications that I build. I'm new at pyqt.

Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.Qstring.fromUtf8
   except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 195)
        self.ClickMeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.ClickMeButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 160, 75, 23))
        self.ClickMeButton.setObjectName("ClickMeButton")
        self.lineUserName = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineUserName.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 40, 211, 20))
        self.lineUserName.setObjectName("lineUserName")
        self.labelEnterName = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.labelEnterName.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 111, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.labelEnterName.setFont(font)
        self.labelEnterName.setObjectName("labelEnterName")
        self.labelMessage = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.labelMessage.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 341, 81))
        self.labelMessage.setText("")
        self.labelMessage.setObjectName("labelMessage")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.ClickMeButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "&ClickMe"))
        self.labelEnterName.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Enter your name."))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

***call app***
import sys
from welcomemsg import *
class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.Qobject.connect(self.ui.ClickMeButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.dispmessage)

    def dispmessage(self):
        self.ui.labelmessage.setText("Hello "+ self.ui.lineUserName.text())

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***error***

```
class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtGui' has no attribute 'QDialog'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Qt5, `QDialog` is in the `QtWidgets` module, not `QtGui`.